# Updating incremental code files not currently managed through version control to a svn repository

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a few code files that are in incremental stages of development.   i want to bring these code files under versioning for better management.  I would use svn for this.

Since these files are lying on my computer and they are not currently a svn working copy since no version control system was used at the first instance,  my question is how do i place/update them under a remotely hosted repository ?

Can we  use a version control for managing code files  that  did not use a source control system at the start ?

Or

Basicaly what i want to know is how do you bring a current project under source control that did not use source control to manage code at the start?

If we can, then  what commands/process do i need to follow to achieve this?

Comment: Try google, its pretty easy if you're familiar with svn and even if you arn't its not bad.

Comment: i tried google but not much help... i suppose i'm not sure what combination of keywords would exactly yield the result

Comment: http://www.jaredrichardson.net/articles/svn-cheat-sheet.html try that, if you have more specific questions let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html

Your IDE integration should provide a nice import option (in Eclipse, that's Team -> Share Project).

If you have several versions of a project in different folders, you can somewhat "import" the version history manually.

Say, import the oldest version you have into SVN. Then overwrite/add the files from your second version and commit; repeat this for all versions you have and that should be it.

I think it's probably a waste of time, though.

Comment: i know about import... if i have say five folders of incremental code lying independent of each other and not under source control can i use import on each folder to bring successive code folders under versioning?

Comment: You mean you have foo_v1, foo_v2 which are successive versions of the same code and you want to import that into the repository? If so, I'd probably just import the latest one and be done with it. If you really, really want to keep history, svn import the oldest version, overwrite the contents of your working copy with the next version, commit, rinse, repeat.

If the folders are not related, just import them to separate folders in your SVN repo hierarchy (or different repos, if appropriate- although by default you should have a single repo).

Comment: yes  a couple of folders are like  foo_v1, foo_v2  which are successive versions of the same code. However the rest of folders might just contain 1 and only 1 file, the one that was new feature/functionality addition to  code or improvement/succession over an existing code file in foo_v1 or  foo_v2

Comment: I have another issue at the moment though, I'm not sure if you could help me with this but i'll just mention it in case you could help.   I am using RabbitVcs client for svn on Ubuntu Linux and it doesn't show me the 'Commit' command when i right click on the Working copy folder. I did as you said, imported the oldest folder to remote repository and then did a checkout from repository to create a working copy(WC) on local system. Then i overwrote the WC with newer code files from the next code folder, however when i try to commit, the option doesn't show up on right clicking on WC.

Comment: @ Alex - I asked another question on SO  regarding this issue, if you'd like to answer there then here's the link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841205/rabbitvcs-and-commit