# RabbitVcs and Commit

Tags: svn, commit

I am using RabbitVcs client for svn on Ubuntu Linux and it doesn't show me the 'Commit' command when i right click on the Working Copy folder.

I am trying to bring a project under Version Control  system that did not use source control to manage code at the start.

The project has a few folders  with code files that are either successive versions of the same code with changes or completely new code files that did not exist in the previous folder such as a new feature/functionality addition to code.

On a suggestion provided here, what i did to accomplish the task was that i imported the oldest code folder to remote repository, and then did a checkout from remote repository to create a working copy(WC) on local system.

Then i overwrote the WC with newer code files from the next code folder, however when i try to commit the latest version of WC to remote repository, the commit option doesn't show up on right clicking on WC.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commit option is there, just that it doesn't show up on the main working copy folder but does show up when you right click on the svn sub-folder inside it.

Comment: Sometimes the commit option appears outside of the 'RabbitVCS SVN' grouping menu.

Answer (score 1):

Have you destroyed somehow the .svn hidden folders?

All SVN clients rely on the .svn folder to know that something is a working copy and to be able to operate correctly. You should be esp. careful with them- no deleting them (except if deleting the folder that contains them) and no moving them around.

If you have a checkout such as:

- a/
- a/.svn
- a/b
- a/b/.svn

And remove the b folder and then copy a new b folder, SVN clients will get confused.

Try copying a file at a time, you'll see the WC doesn't get borked. Some operation you are performing is corrupting the .svn folder.

Another possibility is that Rabbit is not working correctly. I'd also suggest using command-line Subversion. I guess Rabbit does use it underneath, but it might not be 100% accurate or it might not be showing you errors or something.

Answer (score 1):

This could well be a bug of the new version, see

[Issue 632: No checkout/update/commit options from the menu](http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=632)

Answer (score 0):

i also met the same problem - right click the document, but didn't show the 'commit', 'update' option.

i used rabbitvcs and ubuntu.

my solution is : do checkout first, then right click the document and you'll find the 'commit', 'update' option.

hope to helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of RabbitVCS, just right click on the top level directory, point to RabbitVCS SVN and select Release Lock... menu item. This will allow you to commit or update files.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the same problem through Ubuntu terminal.
Simply, go to the folder in the terminal and use the svn command as explained.
I used the following reference [HScript.com](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/svn-commands/commit.html) that helped.

> svn ci <filename> -m <log message> 
> or
>  svn commit <filename> -m <log
> message>
>  <filename> - You can either use a file name or folder name or
> need not use it.
>  The single file will be uploaded if a name is given
> or all files with new revision in that folder will be uploaded.
>  <log
> message> - Give the message about the changes that are done in the
> current revision of the file or files.